# Send email or report only when a field value is updated

Tags: trigger, workflow, standard-objects, field-update, email-alert

I have a rich text field on contact object.

I want to send an email whenever the content in the rich text field changes. 
I have enabled field history tracking. If reporting is a right way to achieve this, I need the report to clearly specify that there is a change. Or can a report be sent only when there is a change?

I have created a workflow rule, to use the "ISCHANGED" function.
But, I get this error: Error: Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula.
Below is a snapshot of the same.

[image]

I know that I can write a trigger, use emailmessaging to send email. Is there any simple and efficient way to do this ?

**[Update]**
I was able to achieve this through process builder, because I just read that workflow rule does not allow to track changes for rich text field.

But still, I would like to know if this can be done through reporting.. since reports do not need any deployments/ CI process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ISCHANGED()` function is available only in [specific contexts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5):

> This function is available only in:
>
> - Assignment rules
> - Validation rules
> - Field updates
> - Workflow rules if the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited .
> - Formula criteria for executing actions in Process Builder.

Because your Workflow Rule is set to evaluate the rule any time a record is edited to meet criteria, you cannot use the `ISCHANGED()` function.

Salesforce Reporting is not a particularly good match for this requirement, but it can work. You could use a Workflow Rule that does comply with the above restrictions to populate a Date field with `TODAY()` each time the field changes, and subsequently create a subscription to that report.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to write an Apex Trigger to compare new and old value. I found a similar discussion here

[Trigger.new contains OLD value of edited Rich Text Area in come cases?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228871/trigger-new-contains-old-value-of-edited-rich-text-area-in-come-cases)